# Getting uninitialized constant while calling class method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting `uninitialized constant`  while accessing other `class` method from `model` class

## Model class

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :fetch_data
  belongs_to :user
 
  def fetch_data
    self.name = 'test'
    self.get_groups = Groups.new(self.department).verdict
  end
end
```

## Groups class

```
class Groups
  @@current_state

  def initialize(department_arrangement)
    @@current_state = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(department_arrangement))
  end
  
  def self.get_groups
    @@current_state.each do |row|
      # code
    end
    return # return some value
  end
  # more code
end
```

## Stack trace

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Post::Group):
  app/models/post.rb:17:in `fetch_data'
  app/controllers/post_controller.rb:19:in `create'

  Rendered /Users/komal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (21.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/komal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (8.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/komal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.8ms)
```

Basically I want to pass a parameter `self.department` coming from `views` and using that variable I am doing some calculation and saving the result in database. What is the right way to do it? I want to keep `get_groups` method in `group class`.

## Edit-1

I have added `config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app/utility )` in my `application.rb` and `require 'group_utility' in model class`. Now I can see it's calling the constructor but it is throwing `No method exist: get-groups` Error.

Comment: can someone please explain me why it's downvoting?

Comment: I am learning ruby and coming from java background. I tried but not working. can someone please help me in that?

Comment: A stack trace of the error would be useful. Also, an unrelated note: the `initialize` method is called on every `Groups.new`, and such method is setting the `@@current_state` which is a class variable. In other words, every `Groups.new` alters the current state of the whole class. Consider using an instance variable (ie: only one @ char: `@current_state`) if it's appropiate

Comment: @tonchis Thanks for commenting, So you are saying that I need to use local variable of each method instead of global variable? If yes, then how can I initialize the `@current_state` for all other methods?

Comment: Let's start by solving the `uninitialized constant` problem first, then worry about the logic itself. The constants in the code you're showing are `Post`, `ActiveRecord::Base`, `Group`, and `Marshal`. One (or more) of those constants is not being loaded by the time that LOC is executed. We cannot see where this happens without seeing the stack trace of the error.

Comment: I can see http://pastebin.com/A3CXVz5g in my rail console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby namespaces the constants. Here, by calling `Groups` inside the `Post` class, it's assuming that it will find the constant within said class.

If you want to refer to a constant declared outside the current namespace, you need to prepend `::` to it:

```
self.get_groups = ::Groups.new(self.department).verdict
```

If doing this now raises `NameError (uninitialized constant Groups):` then the file where the `Groups` class is created is not being loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now I am getting `undefined method `each' for "[[\":one\"]]":String` in `get_groups` method. But it works fine when i running this ruby file independent

Comment: `@@current_state` is not null because I can see the passed parameters in exception

Comment: `@@current_state` is null

Answer (score 1):

You need to "require" the other class and if they are in the same directory use "require_relative".

```
require_relative 'Groups'
```

I'm new to rails as well, and from what I have seen this is mostly never done. The extra class would be stored as a helper.

Comment: I did but it's throwing `cannot load such file -- ` exception

Comment: @komalsharma Then I would suggest putting the code into the model itself as private methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Post::Group):
```

What does it mean?

`Group` class is not accessible or it's not initialized yet. To make it accessible you have to add `config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app/<name of the directory>)` in `applicaiton.rb`

Now the class will load automatically when you start the server. 
Adding `require '<class-name>'` in your model class will make it accessible . As you said you are coming from `java` background, `requuire <class-name>` is equivalent to `import Groups`.

you are all set, Now just need to access the class method and you can do it by following code (mentioned by @tonchis)

```
self.get_groups = ::Groups.new(self.department).verdict
```